Is it possible to bypass the "OEM Unlock" feature in developers options menu by modifying the OEM_UNLOCK flag in the "persist" partition?
I have a Moto G9 Plus that is stuck in a bootloop. I’ve tried flashing the stock firmware multiple times without success, and I cannot boot into recovery or use a custom recovery ROM since none is installed. My phone's bootloader is currently locked. I’ve obtained the unlock code from Motorola's official website and am seeking a way to unlock it so I can flash a custom ROM like LineageOS.
After researching potential solutions, I found that it might be possible to remove the memory storage from the motherboard and access the persist partition using an UFI device and an eMMC toolkit. Given this, I’m wondering if modifying the OEM_UNLOCK flag in the persist partition could bypass the "OEM Unlock" feature, allowing me to unlock my bootloader through fastboot.
If possible, would this approach break any security measures defined in the vbmeta partition?
Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Desoldering smd flash memory chips is to my knowledge pretty complicated especially if you plan to revert it later. Therefore I don't think there are too many people having experience with soldering and modifying special Android partitions for bootloader unlocking.

You have the unlock code... Can you not get to fastboot? But I am more interested in why if your phone is locked why you can't get to recovery... If it's locked and you can't get to recovery, the most likely case here is the eMMC chip has gone (is going) bad, and even if you get it unlocked and try to flash something it will fail. It is extremely rare for a locked to device to just "brick" for no reason, usually something fails.

@robert That's true, soldering a memory chip is not an easy task at all, but if it works, I'll find the person.

@acejavelin I do have access to fastboot, however when I run fastboot oem unlock [KEY] it fails and says I am required to activate OEM Unlock in the developer options menu first. Also you are right, it is pretty surprising how my phone just bricked by itself even tho I hadn't touched the firmware at all! One night I just came back home realizing how freaking hot the fingerprint sensor had got. I turned off my phone, and next morning it just didn't want to turn on..

that's not how it works. use blankflash to repair phone. flash retail or reteu. unlock OEM unlocking. unlock bootloader from fastboot with unlock code

@alecxs Thank you for the response. Yes, as a result I was in the process if blankflash-ing my phone until I unexpectedly stumbled across the solution (Updated the question).

@Taili you should answer your question and accept it as the answer rather than editing your original post.

@acejavelin question remains unanswered, as the solution has nothing in common with the question

Thanks for the guidance. I'm new to asking questions. I'm going to correct it now

For some (unknown-to-me) reason, the fingerprint sensor was causing the brick. Having mentioned it, the first precursor was the heat coming off of the sensor which I should have checked first. I stumbled on the solution so randomly while checking how my phone would boot even with fingerprint sensor detached as of curiosity which led to its start up.
